# What is this syntax error referring to in this avr sound code to convert a audio raw file to a .h file for the Arduino IDE

Tags: python, syntax, arduino

I am attempting to convert an audio file to .h that an Arudino can read and I can use to play sound through a speaker without having to use an sd card module. So, I was following [this](http://www.webondevices.com/arduino-tone-mp3-sound-with-no-shield) tutorial to use this [avr sound](https://github.com/muayyad-alsadi/avr_sound) program from Github to convert the audio. It instructed me to use this python program to convert it however command prompt gives me an error telling me there's a syntax error in line 23 where the second quotation mark is. Any idea what I did wrong or how I can fix it?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys, os, os.path
from avr_snd import *

SEGMENT_MAX = 256
SEGMENT_TMP = """
#define %s%d_len %d
const unsigned char %s%d[] PROGMEM=%s;

"""

PLAY_TMP = """
void play_%s() {
%s
}
"""

def convert(prefix, file_i, file_o):
    a=array.array('B', (open(file_i, 'r').read()))
    i,j=analyze(a)
    b=array.array('B', compress(a,i,j)).tostring()
    print "size=", len(b)
    out=open(file_o, "w+")
    for l, i in enumerate(range(0, len(b), SEGMENT_MAX)):
        segment=b[i:i+SEGMENT_MAX]
        out.write( SEGMENT_TMP % (prefix, l, len(segment), prefix, l, repr(segment).replace("'", '"')))
    out.write(PLAY_TMP % (prefix, "\n".join(map(lambda i: "avr_sound_play(%s%d, %s%d_len);" % (prefix, i, prefix, i), range(l+1)))))
    out.close();

def main():
  file_i=sys.argv[1]
  prefix='.'.join(os.path.basename(file_i).split('.')[:1])
  file_o=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_i), prefix+".h")
  convert(prefix, file_i, file_o)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Command prompt gives me this error message when I try to convert the file.

```
  File "snd2h.py", line 23
    print "size=", + len(b)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` statement doesn’t exist in Python 3, you must use the `print()` function instead.

See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function